# Azure SQL Database On-Premises Firewall Configuration for external data source

Tags: sql-server, azure, firewall

We have to add an on-premises SQL Server database table as external table in Azure SQL Database.

However, the on-premises firewall requires IP in whitelist to allow incoming connections. What IP does Azure database service use to connect for External Data source ?  OR to put it differently, how do I configure our on-premises firewall to allow Azure to connect to on-premise databases through the External table configuration ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. That said: There's no specific IP address for Azure Database service.

Comment: Please spend 10 minutes talking about your actual problem of what you are really trying to accomplish before you go ahead with your proposed solutions.  I am 98% sure that poking a hole in your firewall for this database linking problem is not the easiest, quickest or the most reasonable solution in your case.

Comment: Trying to add a on premise SQL database table as external table in an Azure database. 

This gives us the ability to perform distributed queries, and transfers using single connection for statements like select into. only issue is for Azure to be able to connect, we will have to allow the connection through our local firewall.